# Maria DB SQL group by and sum query is slow

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, mariadb, query-optimization

My My SQl query is taking 6 sec to execute, I have added index on the where field, but its still same speed, then I remove the where clause and check the speed, the different is very small. So the problem is in SUM and Group By, I have read to optimize Group by adding index on Group BY fields but they are on different columns. Not an Expert in Mysql im a java developer.

```
SELECT
IF(
    categories_1.NAME IS NULL,
    categories.name,
    categories_1.name
  ) AS PARENTCAT,
  categories.NAME AS SUBCAT,
  products.REFERENCE AS PRODREF,
  products.NAME AS PRODNAME,
  SUM(ticketlines.UNITS) AS UNITS,
  SUM(ticketlines.PRICE * ticketlines.UNITS) AS SALES
FROM
  taxes taxes
  INNER JOIN ticketlines ticketlines ON (taxes.ID = ticketlines.TAXID)
  INNER JOIN products products ON (products.ID = ticketlines.PRODUCT)
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN categories categories ON (categories.ID = products.CATEGORY)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN categories categories_1 ON (categories.PARENTID = categories_1.ID)
  INNER JOIN tickets tickets ON (tickets.ID = ticketlines.TICKET)
  INNER JOIN receipts receipts ON (tickets.ID = receipts.ID)
WHERE
  (
    receipts.DATENEW BETWEEN DATE('2021-12-01 00:00:00.000')
    AND DATE('2022-02-18 00:21:00.000')
  )
GROUP BY
  categories.NAME,
  products.REFERENCE
ORDER BY
  PARENTCAT ASC,
  SUBCAT ASC,
  PRODNAME ASC
```

[image]

The Index in on receipts.DATENEW

Comment: I'm suspicious of your joins, but without example data we're a bit stuck to help. In cases where you have a long-running query I find it is incredibly valuable to look at the query planner. For MariaDB's version, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-explain/. This will show you which parts of your query are taking the longest, and hopefully lead you to ways to make it more efficient.

Comment: I want to see how it perform if you remove both of the OUTER JOINs.

Comment: @JamesMcPherson Im checking how i can run show explain, it need a thread id and query complete in 6 secs.

Comment: @FanoFN it reduce down to 2.515 sec / 0.000 sec when removing the outer joins.

Comment: I see, so what do you think? Is 2.515 sec an acceptable performance?